# Using JS code on the WordPress site under Script

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I know WordPress should get a JS code a different and I would ask help what to do with this code:

```
$('table tr:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+8)').addClass('active');

$('#songs-load').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();  
 var $rows = $('.songs-table tr');
 var lastActiveIndex = $rows.filter('.active:last').index();
 $rows.filter(':lt(' + (lastActiveIndex + 10) + ')').addClass('active');
 });

$('#album-load').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
 var $rows = $('.album-table tr');
 var lastActiveIndex = $rows.filter('.active:last').index();
 $rows.filter(':lt(' + (lastActiveIndex + 10) + ')').addClass('active');
 });
```

https://codepen.io/pixelboutiqueuk-the-lessful/pen/JjogZXa

I tried to copy and paste the JS code inside script tag and it does not work. Can you tell me how I should use this code in WordPress?

Comment: Put it in one of your theme’s JS files.

Comment: I tried as stated in the script tag and it does not work

Comment: “Doesn’t work” in what way?

Comment: The result is not obtained as you see it in the codepen and all 20 lines that exist in the example are displayed, so the code is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You can load the script from an external file by enqueuing the external file using the wp_enqueue_script function.

// https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

However, if you do not want to load an extra file, use the wp_add_inline_script instead.

// https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/

Example:

Add this code in the functions.php file.

```
// a custom inline script
function a_custom_script_mod() {
    if ( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'registered' ) ) {
        wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery', '
        (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("table tr:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+8)").addClass("active");

                $("#songs-load").on("click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();  
                    var $rows = $(".songs-table tr");
                    var lastActiveIndex = $rows.filter(".active:last").index();
                    $rows.filter(":lt(\' + (lastActiveIndex + 10) + \')").addClass("active");
                });

                $("#album-load").on("click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();  
                    var $rows = $(".album-table tr");
                    var lastActiveIndex = $rows.filter(".active:last").index();
                    $rows.filter(":lt(\' + (lastActiveIndex + 10) + \')").addClass("active");
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    ');
    }
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'a_custom_script_mod', 9999);
```

Comment: I tried to enter the code you wrote in <script> ... </script>.. its not work

Comment: Did you purge the cache? Do you see any errors in the browser console? Please provide further details about the issue so that we can understand it better.

Comment: The error is that the code actually does not work because as in not the example in codepan I see straight 20 lines and the button does not work and go to the top of the page.

Comment: The code actually works on our end. It starts with 8 entries and display more when the load more button is clicked. Are you sure that Javascript is enabled in your browser?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. So how to get to it? Did you enter this code in a script? Where exactly did you place it and how?

Comment: You have to add the a_custom_script_mod function and the wp_enqueue_scripts hook in the child theme's functions.php file. But if you have not installed a child theme yet, just add it in the parent theme's function.php file.

Comment: Copy and paste the code in functions.php file as it appears in the codepen or as you wrote?

Comment: You have to use the custom inline script that was provided above, or the snippet that is using the wp_add_inline_script function. Add it in the functions.php file.